# SQL Nested Select -Subquery returned more than 1 value-

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Sales` with columns `SalesID`, `SalesName`, `SalesCity`, `SalesState`.

I am trying to come up with a query that only shows salesName where there is one `SalesName` per `SalesCity`. So for example, if SaleA is in Houston and SaleB is in Houston, SaleA and SaleB will not be returned.

```
select 
    SalesName, SalesCity, SalesState
from
    Sales
where
    (select count(*) from Sales group by SalesCity) = 1;
```

I am not entirely sure how to link the inner select back out. I need another column in the nested select to identify the `SalesID`. I am currently stuck and have made no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the names of cities that have only 1 sale by using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` operators. Then use these results in your where clause:

```
SELECT SalesName, SalesCity, SalesState
FROM Sales WHERE SalesCity IN 
(
    SELECT SalesCity
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY SalesCity
    HAVING COUNT(SalesCity) = 1
)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I tried the having, but the key part I was missing was 'IN'. I see how this works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a subquery:

```
select MIN(SalesName) as SalesName, SalesCity, MIN(SalesState) as SalesState
from Sales
group by SalesCity
having count(*) = 1;
```

If there is only one row for the city, then the `min()` will return the value on that row.